# Optimizing Perl script which looks for world-writable files

Tags: optimization, security, perl, file-system

A script which scans a local filesystem and writes to a file a list of world-writable files found on the filesystem.

I ran it on a server with a couple terabytes of storage; not all of it used. In fact, only 195GB have been used. I'm not sure how many files there are, though.

The script takes 23 minutes to run. Is there something I can do to make it run faster?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $dir = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $mtab = "/etc/mtab";
my $permFile = "world_writable_w_files.txt";
my $tmpFile = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $exclude = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";
my $root = "/";
my (%excludes, %devNums);
my ($regExcld, $errHeader);

# Create an array of the file stats for "/"
my @rootStats = stat($root);

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

open MT, "<${mtab}" or die "Cannot open ${mtab}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]);
  }
}

close MT;

# Build a hash of each mountpoint's device number for future comparison
foreach (@mounts) {
  my @stats = stat($_);
  $devNums{$stats[0]} = $_;
}

# Build a hash from /usr/local/etc/world_writables_excludes.txt
if ((! -e $exclude) || (-z $exclude)) {
  $errHeader = <<HEADER;
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!                                                  !!
!! /usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt is    !!
!! is missing or empty. This report includes        !!
!! every world-writable file including those which  !!
!! are expected and should be excluded.             !!
!!                                                  !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


HEADER

} else {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  while (<XCLD>) {
    chomp;
    $excludes{$_} = 1;
}

sub wanted {
  # Is it excluded from the report...
  return if (exists $excludes{$File::Find::name});

  # ...in a basic directory, ...
  return if $File::Find::dir =~ /sys|proc|dev/;

  # ...a regular file, ...
  return unless -f;

  # ...local, ...
  my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);
  return if (exists $devNums{$dirStats[0]});

  # ...and world writable?
  return unless (((stat)[2] & S_IWUSR) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWGRP) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWOTH));

  # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files
  print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");

}

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir($dir or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${dir}, $!") unless (-d $dir);

# Create our filehandle for writing our findings
open WWFILE, ">${dir}${tmpFile}" or die "Cannot open ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";
print(WWFILE "${errHeader}") if ($errHeader);

find(\&wanted, @mounts);

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${tmpFile} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${dir}${tmpFile}") {
  unlink "${dir}${tmpFile}";

} else {
  rename("${dir}${tmpFile}","${dir}${permFile}") or die "Cannot rename file ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";

}
```

Comment: You might try rearranging the filters so that you determine if a file is interesting AFTER you determine if it is world-writable. Also, your test for basic directory will work improperly for any directory named "procedure" for instance.

Comment: Moved the world-writable test to the top. It did not offer a change to the execution time. I also anchored each of the special directories in the regex.

Comment: I would replace `-f` and `stat` calls inside `wanted` with [`File::stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) equivalents.

Comment: I'd try a run using the unix find utility for comparison, e.g. `find / -perm -2 ! -type l -ls`.

Answer (score 1):

here are my suggestions:

Your hash `%excludes` would use less memory, if you would set the value to  `undef` instead of `1`.

You could set `$File::Find::prune=1` in those cases where the whole directory is to be excluded. This shortcuts the search for this directory.

You could also use the cached data of `stat()` afterwards like this `-f _`.

The regex should use anchors (faster and more robust).

Here is the revised `wanted` subroutine (untested).

```
sub wanted {
  my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);

  # Is it excluded from the report...
  if (exists $excludes{$File::Find::name}) {
    $File::Find::prune=1 if (-d _);
    return;
  }

  # ...in a basic directory, ...
  if ($File::Find::name =~ /^\bsys\b|\bproc\b|\bdev\b$/) {
    $File::Find::prune=1 if (-d _);
    return;
  }

  # ... not a regular file, ...
  return unless -f _;

  # ...local, ...
  return if (exists $devNums{$dirStats[0]});

  # ...and world writable?
  my $protection = $dirStats[2];
  my $writemask = (S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
  return unless $writemask == $protection & $writemask;

  # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files
  print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR. This is a nice first answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `Find::File::prune` option? This actually came up on our weekly call today. Would the directory be added to the excludes file?

Comment: @theillien: `File::Find::find()` does a depth-first search over the directory tree. `$Find::File::prune=1` is used to signal 'I am the last leave at this point in the tree. You may return to next upper level of the tree'.

Comment: @theillien: (continuation) The tree traversal engine will stop processing all not yet processed files and subdirectories in this directory then.

Comment: Yup, got that. If I understand it correctly it removes the section of the file name string following the last `/`. This leaves the directory in which it resides. How does the script then know if the directory is considered entirely ignore-able? Unless I'm not understanding what `Find::File::prune` does at all.

Comment: The tree traversal engine keeps the current working directory it is working on in the package variable `$File::Find::dir`. It can be read in the `wanted` subroutine. It enters a subdirectory by setting it as the new working directory. For each found directory and file the `wanted` subroutine will be called. If you want to ignore a directory path, you have to look for it in `$File::Find::name` when `wanted` is called. Since the directory entry is processed before its content, setting `prune=1` and returning means 'ignore this directory'.

Comment: Yes the directory (with complete path) would then be added to the excludes file.

Comment: I added the code at the top of your suggestion and and then added a directory known to have several world-writable files to my excludes file. The script is still writing all of those files to the output file.

Comment: I believe the problem I'm going to encounter with your suggested method is that I need to ignore a directory (let's say `/opt/app/`) which has several sub-directories of varying depths. Using `File::Find::prune` comes up a bit short for this requirement. At least, so far as I can tell.

Comment: What I mean is, I need to ignore all of `/opt/app` rather than one of its sub-directories.